# How to filter RxJS observables of a redux store?

Tags: javascript, filter, rxjs, observable

I am using RxJS to observe when my redux store changes as shown here: https://medium.com/@fahad19/streaming-redux-state-as-an-observable-with-rxjs-390a8f7bc08c

I have an object that looks like this:

```
 {
  commands: [
    {key: 'arrows', isEnabled: true, activeState: 1, numStates: 2 },
    {key: 'focus', isEnabled: false, hotKey: 'f' },
    {key: 'geometry', isEnabled: true, activeState: 1, numStates: 2 },
    {key: 'goToEnd', isEnabled: true },
```

Each item in this 'commands' array becomes a toolbar button in the GUI. I have written code that changes individual properties of each command but now I need to listen subscribe to changes for each command.

How can I take this stream and filter it by `commandkey` so that the observable only triggers when, for example,  the focus command changes its `isEnabled` and/or `activeState` property changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay, I figured out a way to do what I want.  See code below.  Is there any  better way?

```
const store = Rx.Observable.create(function(observer) {
  let state = { commands: [
    {key: 'arrows', isEnabled: true, activeState: 0, numStates: 2 },
    {key: 'focus', isEnabled: false, hotKey: 'f' },
    {key: 'geometry', isEnabled: true, activeState: 1, numStates: 2 },
    {key: 'goToEnd', isEnabled: true }]
  };

  observer.next(state);

  state = { commands: [
    {key: 'arrows', isEnabled: true, activeState: 1, numStates: 2 },
    {key: 'focus', isEnabled: true, hotKey: 'f' },
    {key: 'geometry', isEnabled: true, activeState: 1, numStates: 2 },
    {key: 'goToEnd', isEnabled: true }]
  };

  observer.next(state);

  state = { commands: [
    {key: 'arrows', isEnabled: true, activeState: 1, numStates: 2 },
    {key: 'focus', isEnabled: true, hotKey: 'f' },
    {key: 'geometry', isEnabled: true, activeState: 1, numStates: 2 },
    {key: 'goToEnd', isEnabled: true }]
  };

  observer.next(state);
});


const subscribe = store.map( state => {
    const commands = state.commands.filter( cmd => cmd.key === 'arrows' );
    if( commands.length == 0 ) {
       return undefined; 
    }
    const result = {
       isEnabled: commands[0].isEnabled,
       activeState: commands[0].activeState,
    };
    return result;
})
.distinctUntilChanged( ( a, b ) => a.isEnabled === b.isEnabled && a.activeState === b.activeState )
.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

working sample here: http://jsbin.com/xipaqusivi/1/edit?js,console

Basically I only get a notification when either the isEnabled or activeState property changes for the selected command key specified (arrows in this example)

Answer (score 1):

You can use distinctUntilChanged operator to get notified only when the value changes

```
store.map(state => 
   state.commands.filter(cmd => cmd.key === 'focus')[0].isEnabled)
  .distinctUntilChanged()
```

Comment: I tried that here: http://jsbin.com/qezogasuwe/1/edit?js,console however distinctUntilChanged() doesn't seem to work.  Note in the linked example I'm getting the same result twice.

Comment: Ahh, I see I need to pass a function into distinctUntilChanged to do my comparison.  The default comparison is not correct on returned objects.

Comment: Yup, default comparison is just '==='.  Glad it works now.

Answer (score 0):

You can `filter` the observables based on your condition. Of course you would need to leverage on the `.map()` and `.filter()` function from Array.prototype:

```
store$.filter(store => {
    return store
        .commands
        .filter(command => command.key == 'focus' && command.isEnabled)
        .length; //if length is greater than 0, means condition is met.
})
```

Comment: I can't get that code to run.  See: http://jsbin.com/qukaruxuri/1/edit?js,console

Comment: @MarekKnows.com yeap edited. Sorry was checking on the phone so did not realize it was an object instead.